# C the Heap using in Fuctions still not clear

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I'm still confused about the errors that I get while compiling to solve my code. I tried to make two simple functions. One that initialize an array and put 0 in every index and the other that prints that function out.

Following code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int arraybuilder(int len)
{
    int *array;
    array = (int*) malloc(len * sizeof(int));

    for(int i = 0; i<len; i++)
    {
        array[i] = 0;
    }

    free(array);
    return array;
}

void printarray(int array[], int len)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("array[%d] = %d\n", i, array[i]);
    }
}



int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    int len = 100;
    int *array = arraybuilder(len);

    printarray(array, len);

    return 0;

}
```

>

> malloctest.c: In function ‘arraybuilder’:
>   malloctest.c:15:9: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>     return array;
>            ^

And:

> malloctest.c: In function ‘main’:
>   malloctest.c:31:15: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>     int *array = arraybuilder(len);

Thank you in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

```
free(array);
return array;
```

First of all this is a problem given that you are invoking a undefined behavior by trying to use a already freed memory.

Secondly check the return type - it is supposed to return an `int` but returning `int*`. Both the error you faced appeared because of the return type of `int` that you have mentioned. ( To be more clear you returned `array` which is of type `int*` and you said you would return `int`. That's why the warning appears).

In the second case, you were supposedly assigning an `int` to an `int*` that's why it complained.

You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` the conversion from `void*` to `int*` is done implicitly. Check the return value of `malloc` on failure it returns `NULL` handle that case accordingly.

```
int* arraybuilder(int len)
{
    if( len <= 0){
       fprintf(stderr,"Negative size\n");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int *array = malloc(sizeof *array *len );
    if( array == NULL ){
       perror("malloc failed");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<len; i++)
        array[i] = 0;
    return array;
}
```

Then in `main()` when you are done working with this dynamically allocated memory you will free it. In `main()`

```
printarray(array, len);
free(array);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning address and your funtion type is integer change your funtion return type to int * from int.But your program is a example of invalid memory acess after freeing your are returning pointer that will cause program crash.

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed that the function `arraybuilder` returns a pointer however its return type is `int` instead of `int *`.

```
int arraybuilder(int len);
```

Also it is better to specify the type of the parameter as an unsigned integer as for example `size_t` because it is evident that the number of elements in the allocated array shall not be a negative value.

So the function should be declared like

```
int * arraybuilder( size_t n );
```

Within the function the allocated memory is freed, As result the value of the returned pointer is invalid.

```
free(array);
return array;
```

The function implementation can look like

```
int * arraybuilder( size_t n )
{
    int *array;

    array = ( int* )malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( array )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            array[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

The function `printarray` does not change the array. So the first parameter should be declared with the qualifier `const`.

```
void printarray( const int array[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf( "array[%zu] = %d\n", i, array[i] );
    }
}
```

It is the function `main` that is responsible to free the allocated memory. Also before outputting the array you should check whether the returned pointer is not equal to `NULL`. Its code can look like

```
int main( void ) 
{
    size_t n = 100;

    int *array = arraybuilder( n );

    if ( array ) printarray( array, n );

    free( array );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it just a habit, that you're using in the for loop **`size_t i = 0;`** or is it actually better than writing **`int i = 0;`**. Also why is just the array in the if statement. There is no comparison or something like that?

Comment: @Richie In C and C++ sizes of objects are defined as having the type size_t. It is the type that is returned by the operator sizeof and for example by the standard string function strlen. So in general you should use the type size_t  for variables that define sizes. In the function I showed parameters have the type size_t as it is explained above so in loops there are also used variables with the type size_t.